# Read images from a image sheet

Tags: css

I have one image sheet like the one in this link (http://jquerytools.org/media/img/demo-navi.jpg).

I would like to get only a component of that image.

How can we get only component of image in CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this: http://www.guistuff.com/css/css_imagetech1.html

### Cropping X and Y

That first image was kind of a softball. All the cool kids know how to take advantage of cropping an image in both axes. There are several reasons for doing this: You may have images of different sizes and want to place all of them within one file, for example. If you only crop on one axis, you'd be saving a file with the largest possible width or height of the array of images you want to use. Also, there are compression elements that you may want to take advantage of in the PNG file format, like keeping images with the same background color in the same horizontal row, and then having several rows.
Whatever the reason, there actually isn't much more to this than what we've seen so far. Here's another example image:

[image: icons]

```
.icons 
{ 
display: block; 
width: 40px; 
height: 40px; 
background-image: url(images/sixicons.png); 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

You can deduce from this class that the width and height of each icon is 40 pixels, and that the image file name is sixicons.png. I didn't create a very challanging example this time for X/Y cropping in the sense that all of the sub-images are of the same size. As you'll see, however, even if they weren't, you'd still be using a simimlar (though not exact) technique.

First, let's crop the top-left icon:

```
.icon_1 { background-position: 0px 0px; }
```

The markup would be:

```
<span class="icons icon_1"></span>
```

That was, of course, the easiest one. Now let's say we want the middle-bottom icon:

```
.icon_5 { background-position: -40px -40px; }
```

Let's see the CSS for all of the icons:

```
.icon_1 { background-position: 0px 0px; } 
.icon_2 { background-position: -40px 0px; } 
.icon_3 { background-position: -80px 0px; } 
.icon_4 { background-position: 0px -40px; } 
.icon_5 { background-position: -40px -40px; } 
.icon_6 { background-position: -80px -40px; }
```

Comment: Please [don't post only a link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer), try to copy here the relevant parts. This question does not need a whole article as an answer for sure.

Answer (score 3):

The correct terminology is [CSS Sprite](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

You can achieve this using background positioning:

```
div
{
    background-image:url('http://jquerytools.org/media/img/demo-navi.jpg');
    background-position:-20px 80px;
    width:100px;
    height:80px;
}​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lz46r/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [CSS Sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/). There are some very simple tutorials [here](http://stylishwebdesigner.com/21-must-see-css-sprites-tutorials/).

Comment: The first link *isn't* from there. And in any case there's *nothing* wrong with w3schools for quick examples to get newbies started. You guys forget what it was like when you were starting out.

Comment: [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/). Sorry, but when I see a link to their page, I downvote. They are the most dangerous for newbies, because if the fundamentals are wrong, it is harder to become a good webprogrammer. There are thousands of resources that are much better for newbies.

Comment: I agree that the quality of their more in-depth articles is questionable but I can't think of a more accessible resource for quick q&a like the OP, esp. one that has interactivity built in. I'm also saddened that you would vote down what is otherwise a perfectly satisfactory response.

Comment: Try the [Mozilla Development Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/hu/). The only "positive" thing about w3schools is that they have good SEO and appear in the first results whatever you search for (good for lazy people). Try prefixing your searches with `mdn `. Take the time to read through the w3fools link. Do we want new developers to copy-paste these codes? Do we want to have more SQL Injection-prone PHP beginner examples and stuff like that? Even those "accesible resources" are incomplete and wrong. Of course if you remove the link, I remove the downvote.

Comment: "if you remove the link, I remove the downvote" - lol that smells like *blackmail* to me.

But I need the rep, so consider it done ;-)

Comment: Blackmail :). A downvote means that the post needs improvements at least in the downvoter's opinion. That is why you can remove downvotes only after the post was edited.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need:

http://jsfiddle.net/8Eucw/1/

**CSS:**

```
#aBit {
 background-image: url('http://www.google.co.uk/images/nav_logo107.png');
 background-position-x: 114px;
 background-position-y: 63px;
 width: 18px;
 height: 18px;   
}​
```

**HTML:**

```
<img src="http://www.google.co.uk/images/nav_logo107.png" /><br />
<hr />
<img id="aBit" />​
```